# Common Lisp macro variable expansion

Tags: macros, common-lisp, variable-expansion

```
(defmacro foo (x)
    `(defun ,xt ()
         (format t "hullo")))

(foo bar)
```

will not define a function `bart`, since `,xt` is read as the variable `xt` rather than the variable `x` plus a `t`.  But is there a way to get a function `bart` by supplying the argument `bar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the function name (which is a string then) and then convert it to a symbol, for example:

```
(defmacro foo (x)
  `(defun ,(intern (format nil "~aT" x)) ()
     (format t "hullo")))
```

then

```
? (foo bar)
BART
? (bart)
hullo
NIL
```